# Guide for custom drag and drop treeview control (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, treeview, drag-and-drop

I need to do a custom tree with simple drag and drop functions (mainly for reordering tree nodes)

Coding from scratch, are there any guides/examples out there for getting me jumpstarted?

Oh and using jQuery of course!

Answer (score 1):

um... well, not clear on why you can't simply use one of the existing ones, but my guess would be that reading the code from the existing ones should give you a starting poing.

http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html

Comment: I've looked into some 4 or 5 various plugins and they're all flawed for my project in some way... too big and jerky (one was 100kb packed), didn´t work, lacked functions etc...

Since I only need very basic functionality I thought I´d just as well do it from scratch

Comment: Right, your question was where too get jumpstarted, my point was if you look at how they did it, you could glean some ideas.